# How to plot 2 data in a linechart on React-Native

Tags: react-native

I am trying to plot 02 data in the same linechart on React Native. 
I am using react-native-responsive-chart for this purpose. 
I could plot 01 data using this library, although I am not being able to plot 02 data in the same graph. 
Can anyone help me?

```
 export default class Tela02 extends Component {

render() {
    const data = [ 50, 10, 40, 95, -4, -24, 85, 91, 35, 53, -53, 24, 50, -20, -80 ]
    const labels = ['10/01', '11/01', '12/01', '13/01' , '14/01' , '15/01', '16/01', '17/01', '18/01', '19/01', 
    '20/01', '21/01', '22/01','23/01', '24/01']
    const config = {
        line: {
            strokeWidth: 1, 
            strokeColor: '#216D99'
        },
        area: {
            visible: false,
        },
        yAxis: {
            labelColor: '#54a0ff'
        },
        xAxis: {
            visible: true,
            labelColor: '#54a0ff',
        },
        grid: {
            strokeColor: '#c8d6e5',
            stepSize: 30
        },
        insetY: 10, 
        insetX: 10,
        backgroundColor: '#fff'

    }

    return(
        <View>
            <View>
                <Text>{this.props.item.name}</Text>             
                <Text>{this.props.item.email}</Text>
            </View>
            <LineChart style={{height: 500}} config={config} data={data} xLabels={labels}/>

        </View>
    )
}
```

}

Comment: I used VictoryLine in my app to plot 03 datas in the same graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What component are you using? 
I used VictoryLine in my app to plot 03 datas in the same graph. Check the examples in the link --> https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/docs/victory-line

Here is an example also of my code:

```
        <VictoryLegend x={legendWidht} y={legendHeight}
          orientation='horizontal'
          gutter={10}
          style={{ border:{ stroke:"black"}, title: {fontSize: 20} } }
          data={[
             {name: this.props.item.x, symbol:{fill:'blue'}},
             {name: this.props.item.y, symbol:{fill:'green'}},
             {name: this.props.item.z, symbol:{fill:'red'}}
             ]}
        />
```

Where your data has to be in the format -->

{
  "dataX": [{"x": 1549343469000, "y": 0.952728}, {"x": 1549343635000, "y": 0.230757}],
  "dataY": [{"x": 1549343469000, "y": 0.857968}, {"x": 1549343635000, "y": 0.326508}],
  "dataZ": [{"x": 1549343469000, "y": 1.28743}, {"x": 1549343635000, "y": 0.27925}],
};